# multi buildpack not working heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, buildpack

I already have a server setup and the build pack is working... I am trying to setup a new server the same exact way but the build pack isn't working correctly.

The build pack I am using is this https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git

When I push a commit to the old server is looks like this

```
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Multipack app detected
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: geos/gdal/proj
remote:        Using geos version: 3.4.2
remote:        Using gdal version: 1.11.1
remote:        Using proj version: 4.8.0_1
remote: -----> Vendoring geo libraries done
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Python
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
```

but when I push to the new server it looks like this and doesn't use the correct build packs (https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python)

```
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> geos/gdal/proj app detected
remote:        Using geos version: 3.4.2
remote:        Using gdal version: 1.11.1
remote:        Using proj version: 4.8.0_1
remote: -----> Fetching and vendoring geos
remote: -----> Fetching and vendoring gdal
remote: -----> Fetching and vendoring proj
remote: -----> Vendoring geo libraries done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
```

is this maybe because I am using different versions of the build pack on each server since I didn't specify the version on github? If this is the case how do I know which version I am using on the old server so I can correctly setup the new server?... The new server definitely isn't working and hasn't even installed pip.

Comment: im having this problem, can i know how you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has first class multibuildpack support now - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app